# Need a simple, foolproof remote admin for Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, ssh, remote, administration, webmin

I'm running an Ubuntu server 12.10 box and need a foolproof remote admin for my wife/kids who have even less experience of linux than I.

The box only runs as file server and our LAN Minecraft server. I don't need a lot:

- Ability to shutdown/reboot
- Low profile (it's not a powerful box, I may be wrong but I understand that installing a GUI is pretty wasteful in terms of resources)
- Possibly browser based (we'll be using it from many devices)

For myself I can SSH in but I'd like the family to be able to do these simple things with a few clicks. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suspect you don't want your wife and kids to have admin access to the box. If they just need the file server this iis easy to set up via webmin (see answer from @bodhi.zazen below). If you wish to also share calendar and docs I would recommend owncloud. Not sure what the requirements are for Minecraft, but file server is easy to do.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a web (browser) based solution, try webmin.

[image: screenshot]

May be a bit of an overkill, but lower on resources then VNC.

See also : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/webmin

If you want a VNC server, I advise FreeNX, it is by far the fastest VNC server/client.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend VNC and a simple window manager. SSH is the best option, but if you want clicks then VNC is the next best thing. It is wasteful, but you can't have your cake and eat it too.